# I am not been able to read the file contents in java code, passed through extjs code to java spring controller

Tags: spring-mvc, extjs4.1

```
   // Here's my extjs code
    Ext.define('ArticulationAgreement.view.Filechooser',{
        extend : 'Ext.form.Panel',
        alias : 'widget.filechooser',
        mixins: ['Deft.mixin.Injectable', 'Deft.mixin.Controllable'],
        //controller : ['ArticulationAgreement.controller.FilechooserController'],
        width : 1500,
        height : 300,
        bodyPadding: '10 10 0',
        frame: true,

        initComponent : function(){
            var me = this;
            Ext.apply(me, {


                title : 'Add the CSV Files',
                defaults:
                            {
                                anchor: '30%',
                                allowBlank: false,
                                msgTarget: 'side',
                                labelWidth: 100
                            },
                items : [
                        {
                            xtype: 'filefield',
                            id: 'form-file',
                            emptyText: 'Select a File',
                            //maxLength : '30',
                            fieldLabel: 'File Selected',
                            name: 'fpath',
                            buttonText: 'upload file'

                        },

                    {
                            text : 'Save File',
                            xtype : 'button',
                            width: 75,
                            itemId : 'save',
                            layout : 'hbox',
                            anchor : '5%',
                            handler : function(){
                            //console.log(this.up('form').down('textfield[name=file-path]').value);
                            var form = this.up('form').getForm();
                            if(form.isValid()){
                                form.submit({
                                url : 'http://localhost:8080/ssp/api/upload.action',
                                waitMsg: 'Uploading your file',
                                success: function(fp, o) {
                                    Ext.Msg.alert('Success', 'Your file has been uploaded.'+fp.responseText);
                                }
                                });
                            }
                            }
                    },
                    {
                        text : 'Reset',
                        xtype : 'button',
                        width : 75,
                        layout : 'hbox',
                        anchor : '5%',
                        handler : function(){
                            this.up('form').getForm().reset();
                        }
                    }
                ]
            });
            return me.callParent(arguments);
        }
    });
```

//Here is my spring controller code

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public 
   ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(FileUploadBean uploadItem, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("QUERY TO UPLOAD FILE");
        try {

                MultipartFile file = uploadItem.getFile();
                String fileName = null;
                InputStream inputStream = null;
                OutputStream outputStream = null;
              //Exception on next line:
               System.out.println("Test upload: " + uploadItem.getFile().getOriginalFilename());

            //rest of the code

            return null;
        }
```

//I am getting exception in java controller and it gives me response in extjs code as-
//Uncaught Ext.JSON.decode(): You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: 
//please help me if possible, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
         //Extjs Code
          {
                    xtype: 'filefield',
                    emptyText: 'Select a File',
                    //maxLength : '30',
                    fieldLabel: 'File Selected',
                    name: 'file',//change in only this line was needed
                    buttonText: 'Choose File'
           }

           //Spring Controller Code
            @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public @ResponseBody String uploadFile(FileUploadBean uploadItem, BindingResult result) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("QUERY TO UPLOAD FILE");
    try {

            CommonsMultipartFile file = uploadItem.getFile();//changed line
            String fileName = null;
            InputStream inputStream = null;
            OutputStream outputStream = null;

           System.out.println("Test upload: " + uploadItem.getFile().getOriginalFilename());

        //rest of the code
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: According to my experience - While uploading file using extjs and spring the 'name' attribute in extjs code affects most and it should be 'file' while many people do say that attribute name of FileUploadBean class in java must be same as that of extjs filefield but i don't think this might be true because previously i was using some different name rather than 'file' with synchronous to attribute of FileUploadBean, i  also changed MultipartFile to CommonsMultipartFile and all code works fine(I edited code of java).